# Opening an unlisted fragment on a viewpager navigation?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm coupling `BottomNavigationView` with `ViewPager`, it works ok, the main reason for that is the swiping and animation.

There are 3 possibilities on my listener:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_solicitation:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_my_profile:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};
```

However, there are other, unlisted fragments. How can I inflate fragments on the view pager and make it go away once swiped or something else was selected?

Comment: It seems I'm looking for nested fragments. Unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Question is unclear. What's the issue with placing those fragment in `ViewPager`'s adapter?

Comment: I don't want to make it part of the navigation, since it's not.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Added this below the viewpager in the main layout file:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</FrameLayout>
```

Below is the method used to open the new fragment and make viewpager gone:

```
        viewPager.setVisibility(viewPager.GONE);
        fragment = new PostSolicitationFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_down);
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
        ft.commit();
```

And this is the new onNavigationSelectedItems to make it show up again in case the user clicks a menu item.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                viewPager.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_solicitation:
                viewPager.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_my_profile:
                viewPager.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```